# Make route only available through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a method `IndexController@search(Request $request)`which I use for an autocomplete field:

Route:

```
Route::get('/search', 'IndexController@search')->name('index.search');
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#terms').autocomplete({
        source: 'search' // --> http://myapp/search
    });
});
```

The javascript/jQuery works as expected, but it's now possible to call `http://myapp/search` in the browser and access the raw JSON data of the search query. If possible, I'd like to prohibit that. The search method should only be available via javascript.

Is that possible?

Comment: I would say no. If it's accessible from JavaScript, it means it's a resource  which can be requested by the browser...

Comment: Not really, you can add measures to try and prevent it, but ultimately anyone with knowledge of Chrome Dev Tools could see the request and emulate it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So I guess, this is the expected behavior and it's completely usual that JSON results that are supposed to be consumed by a web page are publicly accessible!?

Comment: I don't think someone scraping your page by visiting the request with a browser is what you should be concerned about. If you have sensitive data that end user doesn't need to see (such as `id` usually), just don't return it in the json. And if there's some sensitive data that shouldn't be available to all users, protect it with some form of authentication. But bottom line is, whatever you make publicly available, someone will be able to scrape it - one way or another

Answer (score 1):

There are always ways to get around it. But this will do what you want in the majority of cases:

```
if (!request()->ajax()) {
    abort(404);
}
```

That being said, I'd be more concerned about ajax bots trying to scrape content, than people going through pages by hand

Comment: You mean to write `$request->ajax()` ,

Comment: I mean [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-request). Of course, if you have an instance of the request in a variable `$request`, that will work too.

Comment: I see. There is a `request` helper too (_nods head_.)